# How to restore files from an external drive done with Norton Ghost

Tags: backup, extract, norton-ghost

Our office XP computer crashed this afternoon. I know that we had Norton Ghost doing regular backups on an external hard drive. My question is how do you restore from that backup?

PS. When I plug in the external drive into my own Windows 7 machine it has two folders:
- 9c590f17be2ef53d13bb00be2a
- Norton Backups

I can't open the first one (it says I don't have permissions) but the second one contains a bunch of files with the .v2i extension.

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Have you read the Ghost manual/help file, that should detail backup as well as restore procedures? Do you have a bootable Ghost recovery disc?

Comment: No, I don't have any bootable discs. I'm simply helping my colleagues to restore their system. (And I don't think they have any bootable discs either.)

Comment: You might be able to create one then via a fresh Ghost install on another PC, or manually using WinPE/PartPE etc.

Comment: I just put very detailed instructions for setting up Norton Ghost in a Windows 10 VM that will let you get access to these files:  https://superuser.com/questions/1615820/how-to-restore-an-old-windows-7-norton-backup-from-2008-or-2009-on-a-modern-pc