# How to restore an old Windows 7 Norton backup from 2008 or 2009 on a modern PC?

Tags: windows-7, backup, norton-internet-security, norton-family

While looking through some old files recently on some external hard drives, I came across an old Windows laptop backup set, I think done by Norton Backup (judging by the folder it was in), and I would like to restore it somehow to have a look round.

The backup set was made in late 2008 to early 2009. Do current Norton backup programs cater for this old a backup? The file structure appears to be:

> {name of laptop} > "File Backup Data" > fbfFiles_0xx

The `xx` in `fbfFiles_0xx` being a hex style combo of letters and/or numbers. The files within these folders have an `.fbf` extension.

Does anyone know if this still works, or failing that, is there an old version of Norton Backup (or whatever it was back then that created the backup) that I can download? I may have found something, but in the probable event that it's a red herring, some assistance or advice would be appreciated.

One thing I did think of was to create a Windows 7 VM on Parallels, before then looking for a compatible version of Norton Internet Security and then seeing if it will recognise the backup and restore. However, if there’s a less complicated and laborious way instead, I’d prefer to do that.

Comment: We can't really help you locate a download for a specific program.  Norton Backup (Norton Ghost) hasn't been actively supported in years.  Modern versions of Norton Internet Security won't be able to restore files from their legacy product.

Comment: afaik, only Norton can mount and allow viewing files in the archive, you would have to install an older version of Norton backup to view the archive

Answer (score 0):

Symantec Ghost 15 will be able to recover the data from those files.

I tested getting Symantec Ghost 15 running in a Windows 10 VM.

1. Set up a Windows 10 VM. Initially attach the VM to the network, we'll detach later
2. Download and install [.Net 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22) from Microsoft
3. Make a read-only copy of the backup files available to the VM. With VMWare Workstation this can be done with Shared Folders even when no network card is enabled
4. Turn off networking on the VM. You don't know how safe the ISO is so best to assume that it's not and don't let any traffic get out of the VM
5. Download the Ghost 15 [ISO from archive.org](https://archive.org/details/norton-ghost-15). Mount it to the VM and install it. It requires .Net 2.5 which is included in the .Net 3.5 installation you did in step 2 [image] [image]
6. Run Ghost and select Activate Later. If you do want to actually activate the product, see the bonus section below [image]
7. Under Tasks, click Recover My Files and point it to your files [image] [image]

**Bonus section - activating Ghost 15 under Windows 10**
Even if you have a key for Ghost, it won't activate by default under Windows 10. Fortunately the fix is fairly easy:

1. Go to the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Norton Ghost\Agent" directory
2. Right-click on VProSvc.exe and click Properties
3. Click the Compatibility tab and "Change settings for all users"
4. Tick "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and set it to be "Windows 7" [image]
5. Click OK twice to get out
6. Run **services.msc** as Adminstrator
7. Restart the "Norton Ghost" service
8. Enter the serial number [image]
9. Get Activated confirmation [image]